# Session variable are not handled properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a AspxGriview on aspx page with `id="grdManageFilterRoom"`. I am binding this grid by fetching some data from database. In case of any changes in `Session["grdManageFilterRoom"]` variable it is automatically reflected in `Session["tmpGrdManageFilterRoom"]` variable 
I don't know why it's happening and I want to avoid this behavior. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
   Session["grdManageFilterRoom"] = NameIdPairs<Int32>.GetRooms(companyCode, companyPersonID);          
   grdManageFilterRoom.DataSource = Session["grdManageFilterRoom"];
   Session["tmpGrdManageFilterRoom"] = Session["grdManageFilterRoom"];
```

Comment: des is correct. What is the return type of NameIdPairs<Int32>.GetRooms(companyCode,companyPersonID) like list, array etc.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
Session["tmpGrdManageFilterRoom"] = Session["grdManageFilterRoom"];
```

makes both session variables point to same object (I'm guessing that `GetRooms` method returns reference type), basically it doesn't matter if you are using `Session["tmpGrdManageFilterRoom"]` or `Session["grdManageFilterRoom"]` (because it is the same object).

If want to prevent this, then you need to clone those object(s).

Comment: thanks for your information . I made change in code for using clone object